# Share ViewModel in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Disclaimer**:I'm an Android developer but had to delve into a bit of Swift for a KMM project.

I have a ViewModel set up like so:

```
class MyViewModel:ObservableObject { 
...
var items Array = [Item]()
//the above array gets populated later on. Tried setting it as a state variable to be observed but for some reason the values never got updated 
...
}
```

I have already been able to access some other variables of MyViewModel from my Content View (which is the file it is located in but outside the struct's scope) like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject private (set) var viewmodel: MyViewModel 

var body: some View {...}
...
}
```

However, when I try to access the MyViewModel variables from another struct with a similar setup contained in another file like so:

```
struct TestView {     
        @ObservedObject private var viewmodel = MyViewModel() 
        var body: some View {        
            var cartItems = viewmodel.itemsArray     
        }
    }
```

, XCode shows the *Cannot find type 'MyViewModel' in scope*

Is there a way a ViewModel can be shared across multiple views on swift like it's done in Android/Kotlin?

**EDIT:** Just realised that the ViewModel is contained within `extension ContentView {}` as it makes use of some enums within the extension.
Is there a way to access the variables as it is or do I have to change my code structure? How does this work in swift?

Comment: Could you show us the other struct? Also try to use StateObject instead of ObservedObject & use @Published for your items variable so it could update the view

Comment: `struct TestView {
    @ObservedObject private var viewmodel = MyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        var cartItems = viewmodel.itemsArray
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think it might work

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items = [Item]()
}
```

`@Published` modifier will notify body property if some changes happens.

Then if you want to share your ViewModel, you have to create "source of truth" Some one must own instance.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
      @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
      
      var body: some View {...}
  }
```

Here `@StateObject` create new instance of ViewModel and you can share it.

```
struct TestView {     
        @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel() 
        var body: some View {
        }
    }
```

`@ObservedObject` expects to receive ViewModel instance from elsewhere

Comment: Just realised that the ViewModel is contained within `extension ContentView {}` as it makes use of some enums within the extension.
Is there a way to access the variables as it is or do I have to change my code structure? How does this work in swift?

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/sharedviewmodel-in-kotlin-ec9b09b41a78

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable's name in `MyViewModel` & remove the space. Publish that variable so it can update the view:

```
@Published var itemsArray = [Item]()
```

Also don't add variables to your `View body`, it should only contains element relevant to `View`.

So remove `var cartItems = viewmodel.itemsArray` & instead use `viewmodel.itemsArray` directly. You don't need a new variable.

Note: If your app is `iOS 14+` substitute `@ObservedObject` for `@StateObject`.

Comment: XCode seems to have a issue with me referencing the viewmodel outside the ContentView Struct.
I tried moving the TestView struct into the same ContentView file and still got the same error

Comment: It doesn't depend on which file your struct is in as long as the class isn't marked fileprivate

Comment: Just realised that i had placed the viewmodel within `extension ContentView {}` because of some enums used in the viewmodel. Is there a way I can still access it from another struct as it is? Or would I have to restructure my code?